# How can I convert an Expr to a Tree in Scala 3?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3

I need to convert an `Expr` to a `Tree` doing Scala 3 macro development, and I did not yet find an appropriate conversion mechanism for that.

In Scala 2 there existed a `tree` method on `Expr` which made this task easy as I see, like this:

```
def expr_impl(c: blackbox.Context)(expr: c.Expr[AnyRef]): c.Expr[Expression] = {
    import c.universe._
    expr.tree match {
      //...
    }
}
```

But this method seems to be removed in Scala 3.

I need this to examine the results of using a Quotes expression.
If I use `showRaw`, the output is not verbose, which is a problem is my case:

```
import scala.quoted.*
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.showRaw
import quotes.reflect.*

//...

val obj: Expr[_] = '{object AnObject}
report.error(s"from macro annotation1 ${showRaw(obj)}")
```

This results in a non-verbose output like this: `from macro annotation1 '{ ... }`

Also tried `Printer.TreeStructure.show`, which expects a `Tree` instead of `Expr`, and that's why I need the mentioned conversion, as `Printer.TreeStructure.show` would result in a verbose output.

If there is any method that is verbose and similar to `Printer.TreeStructure.show` and expects an `Expr` as an argument, that would also solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say `.tree` was removed - Scala 3's Quotes should be consider completely new implementation which can have some counterparts to Scala 2's Contexts content but not always and even when it has, it might be named differently.

To turn `Expr[A]` into `quotes.reflect.Tree` you should call `.asTerm` on it - `Term` is a subtype of `Tree`.

And to print AST in raw form rather than a pretty print, one can provide `(using Printer.TreeStructure)` to the `show` extension method (available when you convert `Expr` to `Term` and import things from `Quotes`):

```
inline def printExpr[A](a: A): Unit = ${ printExprImpl[A]('{ a }) }

def printExprImpl[A: Type](expr: Expr[A])(using quotes: Quotes): Expr[Unit] = {
  import quotes.*, quotes.reflect.*
  report.info(expr.asTerm.show(using Printer.TreeStructure))
  '{ () }
}
```